# How to call 2 fluxes in parallel and manipulate on them afterwards

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

So I'm new to reactive programming and writing my first program using spring web-flux and I want to call 2 resources in parallel but I couldn't find how.

I've already Implemented the following methods

```
public Flux<Date> getDatesToExclude(); //fetches dates from external api

public Flux<UserDates> getAvailableUserDates(); //fetches dates from a json file
```

UserDates DTO

```
public class UserDates{
  private String user;
  private List<Date> dates;

  //* getters setters *//
}
```

and I want to implement the following which should

1. request getDatesToExclude() and getAvailableUserDates() in parallel.
2. filter getAvailableUserDates() to the specific user.
3. filter out the dates to exclude.

```
public Flux<UserDates> getAvailableUserDates(String user);
```

I tried to chain the methods using **zipWith** but found it would work on the items 1 by 1 which doesn't seem useful in this case.

Do I have to use completableFuture in this case?

Comment: You can do `collectList` on all Fluxes and then `zip` them together.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `collectList()` and also make sure your different flux executions will be executed on different threads. Below is an example that you can easily adapt to your code.

```java
Mono<List<String>> words = Flux.just("sun", "sky", "beach", "water", "sun", "tree")
        .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(100))  // just to slow down emitting, for testing
        .filter(user -> user.equals("sun"))     // we want to filter only "sun" words
        .collectList()                          // collect all the filtered items to a List
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());    // when subscription is made, the process with start on parallel scheduler

Mono<List<Integer>> values = Flux.just(1, 2, 6, 1, 20, 31, 4, 1, 3, 21, 44, 67, 1, 90, 87)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(200))  // just to slow down emitting, for testing
        .filter(value -> value.equals(1))       // we want to filter only values equal to 1
        .collectList()                          // collect all the filtered items to a List
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());    // when subscription is made, the process with start on parallel scheduler

Mono.zip(words, values)
        .doOnNext(tuple -> {
            // do whatever you want with
            // tuple.getT1() - list of words results
            // tuple.getT2() - list of values results
            // I use doOnNext() just for print something, but you should use the operator that depends on your purposes
            System.out.println(String.format("Words list size: %s, values list size: %s",
                    tuple.getT1().size(), tuple.getT2().size())
            );
        })
        .subscribe();

Thread.sleep(10000L);
// just for testing purposes since all the processes after subscribe()
// happen on other threads
```